# VS2008 Web Service Project missing Data Menu and Data Sources

Tags: database, visual-studio-2008, datasource, menuitem

VS2008 Web Service Project missing Data Menu and Data Sources:
Simply invisible, Can't find it and just cant add a connection to my database using that wizard. why is it missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the 'Data' menu is not available for a web application.  Not exactly the same issue, but similar.

I found that if I navigate to the 'Server Explorer' (Ctrl+W, L) (also found via menu item 'View'->'Server Explorer'), and highlight a defined data connection my 'Data' menu choice reappears.  But the sub menu choices are different.  Rather than having 'Data'->'Show Data Sources', or 'Data'->'Add New Data Source...', I get 'Data'->'New Query', and 'Data'->'Modify Connection...'.

Answer (score 0):

Use View --> Server Explorer.

Comment: i already added a link to my database in there, but i have no access to the wizard that also makes the dataset automatically and imports the tables, views and stuff into that .xsd file and the connectionString.

Comment: I need it to refresh the database, because i changed some of the columns in a database i already added before... but answering my previews question would help me more.. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Happens only when I set up a WebService project.